# Can I reprint the Ubuntu Server installation guide?

Tags: server

May I ask? If I print the whole installation guide and add it to our Thesis Appendix for installation guide for the ubuntu server, Am I liable for any legal circumstances?

Thanks.

PS: I just don't wanna be sued.

Comment: A bibliographic reference wouldn't be enough?

Comment: Sir, Our professors are requiring us to have an installation guide for everything we've done to our thesis... From hardware installation up to the network configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precise answer depends which document you're taking about.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/index.html is under GPL so as long as you include it's license in the appendix, you're probably fine.

Other newer help.ubuntu.com content is available under a CC-SA license. Again, this means it's probably fine.

Both these licenses are viral in that they force derivative work to share the same license so you will need to ensure they are verbatim copies and clearly added as referenced appendices, not integral parts of your work... I say this because your school might want to claim an exclusive copyright, which wouldn't be possible. Does that make sense?

Other guides are under other licenses. You would have to see what you're dealing with.

Comment: Yes, this is a big help, because my co league tells me to just edit them, but as far as I know as long as I print the license together with the document it would be fine, because we are giving credit to the people who actually made the installation guide in the first place. As I study a bit of the intellectual property code, even if I rephrase the sentences as long as the thought is the same it is still the property of the person who made it... Thank you very much, I was referring to the Ubuntu Server 12.04 Installation Guide...Thanks to the team who made ubuntu possible, It's a life savior.